# Match an actual dollar symbol in php regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I haven't used regex in a long time and can't figure out how to match an actual dollar symbol and any reference to dollar symbol and regex tells me about the special meanings and cases. I need to match a `$`. I expected that `\$` or `$$` was supposed to escape it, but I'm still not matching it.

Here's my text

```
(WW) Capacity Charge
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . $ 123.45
WW Commodity Charge  . . . . . . . . . $ 67.89
```

**I'm trying to capture `123.45`** I figured I should just match the first occurrence where some characters are sandwiched between the dollar symbol, space and a newline. Here are a few of the regexes I've tried.

```
preg_match("|(?<=\$\s)(.*)(?=\n)|",$data[1],$matches); //no matches
preg_match("|(?<=$\s)(.*)(?=\n)|",$data[1],$matches); //no matches
preg_match("|(?<=$)(.*)(?=\n)|",$data[1],$matches); //no matches
preg_match("|(?<=\$)(.*)(?=\n)|",$data[1],$matches); //no matches
preg_match("|(?<=$$)(.*)(?=\n)|",$data[1],$matches); //no matches
```

Just to check that something matches I even did

```
preg_match("|(?<=\.)(.*)(?=\n)|",$data[1],$matches); // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . $ 123.45
preg_match("|(?<=.)(.*)(?=\n)|",$data[1],$matches); // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . $ 123.45
preg_match("|(?<=1)(.*)(?=\n)|",$data[1],$matches); // 23.45
```

**How can I match the text between the `$` and the newline?**

Comment: Thanks. Wow, you solved it three ways. Use single quotes OR escape it twice OR use a character class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in double quotes so you need to escape twice (once for PHP, then once for PCRE). I prefer a character class though because that works in all regex flavors.

```
(?<=[$]\s)(.*)(?=\n)
```